# Landing Page Limitations in Cloud Pages [Salesforce Marketing Cloud]

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

This is my first time working with Cloud Pages and I've hit a snag almost immediately. I am attempting to build a custom preference center but the landing page appears to choke on the LookUpRows() call. Are Landing Pages in Cloud Pages somehow limited in the ampscript they can call? Is there documentation on this?

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The CloudPages documentation is at https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/cloudpages/

Comment: Can you verify that this LookUpRows call works in a regular page?

Comment: As soon as I add this code

Comment: As soon as I add this line...
SET @subscriberRows = LookUpRows("SubscriberDE", "Email_Address", "myemail@precisiondialogue.com") 
...the page fails. I've used this function many. many times before in custom preference centers and I've triple checked name of date extension and field name. I can't check in regular page because only Cloud Pages are installed for this client.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question now. I got in touch with one of the product specialists at SFMC and was informed that the failure of the requestParameter() method was a known bug. It was something that had not been enabled but was fixed with their update on Friday, 1/21/2015. I have confirmed that my code now works.

It is rather disturbing--but unfortunately not surprising--to me that SFMC would sell this product to a client and expect us to deliver a solution with such a basic, major function not working! I believe that when they are actually done with beta-testing this live product, it should support all the functions of the existing landing pages.

--wck

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not fixed as of today (November 20th, 2015). My code throws a 500 Internal Server Error anytime LookupRows is accessed from AMPScript or SSJS. More specifically, I am using the Web Collect functionality within Cloud Pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful - but do you have the appropriate gears enabled in your account?

See FAQ here - https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/cloudpages/cloudpages_frequently_asked_questions_faqs/

> Q. I don't see a gear for what I am trying to do, what are my options?
>
> A. In addition to the drag-and-drop gears, some CloudPages editions
>   include the option to input custom HTML, AMPscript, and JavaScript
>   with the HTML gear. Here you can copy and paste your HTML, AMPscript,
>   and JavaScript into the text box and it will create the content
>   specified.